# How does the Where method run?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

My [code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i56jtJ) is:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class D {
   public string Value { get; set; }
   public D(string v) { this.Value = v; }
}
public class Program
{
   public static void Main()
   {
       List<D> DD = new List<D>();
       DD.Add(new D("2018-11-08"));
       DD.Add(new D("2018-12-01"));
       var dd = DD.Where(d=> { 
          Console.WriteLine($"In predicate: {d.Value}"); 
          return d.Value=="2018-12-01"; 
       });

       var dl = dd.ToList();
       foreach (var d in dl) {
         Console.WriteLine($"Final: {d.Value}");
       }
   }
}
```

The output is:

```
In predicate: 2018-11-08
In predicate: 2018-12-01
Final: 2018-12-01
```

If `DD` contains 1 million elements, will the lambda in `DD.Where` execute 1 million times?

What if `DD` is a table from SQL Server?

Comment: That's explained in LINQ tutorials. In this case you are calling Enumerable.Where which is an iterator that filters one IEnumerable<T> and returns another. With ORMs like EF Core, you are using Queryable.Where. A Queryable represents a *query*. It doesn't run itself. The provider will convert the LINQ query to SQL or whatever is needed

Comment: If you add `AsParallel()` you have `Parallel LINQ` which *partitions* the data into roughly as many partitions as there are cores and runs the rest of the query on each separate partition.

Comment: @TheGeneral So the presence of a statement that references `d` makes a difference in how the query is constructed?

Comment: As for SQL, *this* expression wouldn't run at all because it can't be converted to SQL. If you fixed it to `Where(d=> d.Value == new DateTime(2018,12,1))` you'd get a query with a `WHERE Value=@p0` clause, where `@p0` would be a datetime parameter with the value `2018-12-01`. Performance would depend on indexing and column statistics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If DD contains 1 million elements, will the lambda in DD.Where execute
>   1 million times?

The answer *depends on the eager operation*. in this specific case *yes* because the eager operation is `ToList` but say it was `First()`, `Any()` it would short-circuit as soon as it finds an element that meets the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

The query syntax where basically creates a method and delegate, and calls the method syntax version with it. Whatever you call where with is turned into a single method and then called through a delegate on each element of the source sequence till it finds the result.

So possibly what you mean by the one checks being passed as a whole expression that's what is happening.

```
Where ( d.Value=="2018-12-01")
It will turn into a single method call like this

bool FindValueExample(var d){
  return (d.Value=="2018-12-01");
}
```

and is then called on each element.